# How to output all the html including header files code in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax that fetches data and displays in the table when clicked on the button now the problem is everything works fine but when I see the source code it just shows the ajax code that is returned by call. Now I have implemented history.js and stuff and when I go to some page and comeback I only see the returned query .... is there a workaround to this? or something that might be helpful...

Index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="load_ajax">Show content</button>
        <div class="query"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

myquery.js

```
$('.load_ajax').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "phone.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $(".query").load(html);
        }
    });
});
```

phone.php

```
echo "Database returned this string...";
```

Comment: You've chained the `done` call to the click event handler, not the ajax call

Comment: @adeneo check the code!